# Flutter version solving failed,google_map_location_picker

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am trying to add google_maps_flutter and google_map_location_picker in flutter project to use it,but the problem is that the last version ^4.1.7 isn't compatible with other packages in App,and i get every time this error:

```
because myapp depends on both image_picker ^0.8.4+2 and google_maps_flutter ^1.1.0, version solving failed.
```

full error:

```
Because image_picker >=0.7.4 depends on flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle ^2.0.1 and google_maps_flutter >=0.5.22 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle ^1.0.0, image_picker >=0.7.4 is incompatible with google_maps_flutter >=0.5.22 <2.0.0-nullsafety.
So, because myapp depends on both image_picker ^0.8.4+2 and google_maps_flutter ^1.1.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because myapp depends on both image_picker ^0.8.4+2 and google_maps_flutter ^1.1.0, version solving failed.)
```

the problem is not in image_picker alone,but in most packages in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  table_calendar: ^2.1.0
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.5
  line_icons: ^2.0.1
  dio: ^1.0.0
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  flag: ^5.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.4
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+2
  xfile: ^1.1.0
  getwidget: ^2.0.3
  path: ^1.8.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.30
  google_map_location_picker: ^3.3.4
```

Is there a good solution to avoid conflict between packages version?

Comment: do you try to update `google_maps_flutter` package? the last is 2.0.11 and you have 0.5.22

Comment: I did,i changed version of both google_maps_flutter and google_map_location_picker to the latest version,but also i get a version solving error

Comment: I had this problem so many times and only you can do is update plugins are in conflict. If after that you still have the problem you have two options: find what versions are compatibles changing versions or use other plugins (or custom code).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the pubyaml plugin version with this code. This will remove the conflict.

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  table_calendar: ^2.1.0
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.5
  line_icons: ^2.0.1
  dio: ^1.0.0
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  flag: ^5.0.1
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  cloud_firestore: ^0.5.0
  firebase_storage: ^5.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.6.2+1
  image_picker: 0.8.0+4
  xfile: ^1.1.0
  getwidget: ^2.0.3
  path: ^1.8.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.5
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.10
  google_map_location_picker: ^4.1.7
```

Comment: I got this error:
The plugins `cloud_firestore, firebase_auth, google_map_location_picker` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.

Comment: @MohamedAmin this is not an error it is the warning. If you want to remove the warning. update all the dependencies to their latest version. but If you have coded the application previously. This will do. and accept the answer if it solves the proble.